# Confusion in understanding epsilon delta definition of limit with a discontinuous function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

To understand the definition (from Wikipedia)
[image]

I have taken a function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 5 \quad &\text{if $x \le 2,$} \\ 5 \quad &\text{if $x=3$,} \\ 5 \quad &\text{if $x\ge 4$,} \end{cases}
$$

I also see that $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta=2 \gt 0, \forall x \in D, 0 \lt |x-3| \lt \delta \implies |f(x) - 5| \lt \epsilon$ where $D = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{(2,3) \cup (3,4)\}$

With this, it seems the limit for $f(x)$ exists at $x=3$ even tough there is a big gap around $x=3$. Wondering if I'm misinterpreting the definition! Is there any bound on the gap in the neighborhood of $x=c$, that I'm not able to gather from the definition of limit.

Comment: Why is $f$ discontinuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're quoting [this passage from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_for_real_valued_functions). Note the condition stated at the beginning of that paragraph, that $c$ has to be a **limit point** of $D$. If it's not (like $c=3$ in your example), then it's not meaningful to even begin talking about “$\lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x)$”, so the limit doesn't exist in that case.

By the way, your function **is** actually continuous (since, well, it satisfies the definition of continuity, as can be verified). Its domain is **disconnected**, but that's a different concept.